# Lambda in python (boto3) "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed: doesn't like InstanceID

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am writing this lambda in Python boto3 sdk in AWS.
All I am trying to do is bring up all the ec2 instances. After adding all the instances to a List, I am able print all the list of instances. I am using EC2 waiter to wait until all instances come up.

It throws a message saying parametervalidation error at this line:
"waiter.wait(InstanceIds=all_instance_ids)"

```
  import json
  import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
      aws_mgmt_console = boto3.session.Session()
      ec2_console_resource = aws_mgmt_console.resource('ec2')
      ec2_console_client = aws_mgmt_console.client('ec2')

      #starting all instances at the same time
      #First step get the list of all instances

      all_instance_ids=[]
      for each_instance in ec2_console_resource.instances.all():
            all_instance_ids.append(each_instance)

       #step 2 create  a waiter       
       waiter=ec2_console_client.get_waiter('instance_running')
       waiter.wait(InstanceIds=all_instance_ids) 
       print("All Your ec2 instace are up and running")
```

"errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter InstanceIds[0], value: ec2.Instance(id='i-06a380ffcdb0581c6'), type: <class 'boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Instance'>, valid types: <class 'str'>\nInvalid type for parameter InstanceIds[1], value: ec2.Instance(id='i-069263b1d8fae9b87'), type: <class 'boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Instance'>, valid types: <class 'str'>",
"errorType": "ParamValidationError",
"requestId": "beb371b8-fa82-4274-8244-415341bef376",
"stackTrace": [
"  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 38, in lambda_handler\n    waiter.wait(InstanceIds=all_instance_ids) #40 checks after every 15 sec\n",

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
for each_instance in ec2_console_resource.instances.all():
```

returns a list of `ec2.Instance()` entities.

However, this line:

```
waiter.wait(InstanceIds=all_instance_ids)
```

is expecting the instance IDs to be text strings.

Therefore, it should use:

```
all_instance_ids.append(each_instance.id)
```

That's why it is saying:

> Invalid type for parameter InstanceIds[0], value: ec2.Instance(id='i-06a380ffcdb0581c6'), valid types: <class 'str'>